# How many examples of the adverbial form N.x2 + 이 (e.g. 쌍쌍이, 곳곳이) are there?

Tags: word-formation

> 쌍= a pair; 쌍쌍이 = in pairs 
>  곳=a place; 곳곳이 = everywhere

I've noticed these two examples of this pattern, but I'm wondering how many others there are? If there are lots, how can I guess which nouns I might be able to do this with?

Comment: There are many words like these in English too. hokey-pokey, razzle-dazzle, super-duper, boogie-woogie, teenie-weenie, walkie-talkie, hoity-toity, wingding, ragtag, easy-peasy, bric-a-brac, chit-chat, criss-cross, ding-dong, jibber-jabber, kitty-cat, knick-knack, pitter-patter, splish-splash, zig-zag, flimflam, baby-shmaby, cancer-schmancer and fancy-schmancy. This is called [reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find some other examples for compound adverbs that are made by reduplication(**첩어**) of a noun + adverbializer suffix (이):

**간간이, 겹겹이, 골골샅샅이, 곳곳이, 길길이, 나날이 , 다달이, 땀땀이, 몫몫이, 번번이, 샅샅이,
알알이, 앞앞이, 일일이, 줄줄이, 집집이, 짬짬이, 철철이, 틈틈이**

Besides, in [Cambridge Language Surveys *The Korean Language*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521369436) (page 257) you can find some explanations about this word structure.

PS:

Since I coudn't copy-paste those explanations, I just added an image of that page of the book here:

[image]